# do I need setup babel and webpack manually in 2021 in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a new project with `npx create-react-app` command, does this command automatically install and configure babel and webpack for me or do I have to do it manually. I have read an instruction on  this link https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/. I think what it is  saying that I don't need to configure babel or webpack, `npm run build` command does all for me.It would be super useful if you explain in a beginner-friendly way. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: this is a question you should present to the developers of the tool, it is not the purpose of SO to answer that kind of questions

Answer (score 2):

Don't need.  Because Babel and Webpack are already dependent on React-Scripts, these dependencies are installed by default

create-react-app provides some default configurations.You can use the following commands to manipulate and display the configuration

```
npm run eject
```

Comment: Keep in mind however that `npm run eject` is irreversible

Comment: do you mean I don't have install those packages then if I eject the project?

Comment: @DiliShod 
if you don't eject the project ,those packages be dependent on [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts)

Comment: if you eject the project,those packages will display in package.json for the current project .

Comment: What I am asking for is that I have read an instruction on this link https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/. I think what it is saying that I don't need to configure babel or webpack, npm run build command does all for me.It would be super useful if you explain in a beginner-friendly way.

Comment: @DiliShod Yes, Babel and Webpack are already installed, because React-Scripts are already installed.